# Moving Wordpress directory

Tags: mysql, directory, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am a web developer who has mainly worked with custom solutions - I am not in any way a Wordpress developer.

One of my clients wants a Wordpress site, so I built it for them using a purchased theme. I built the website using a subdirectoy, and I now need to bring it over to root.

I first need to update the database file as per the theme installation (change all instances of www.domain.com/wpsite/ to www.domain.com/). I then move all the files over to the root directory and change the permalink settings in the Wordpress admin panel.

When I do this, only half the page loads. The background (which happens to be an animation) does not load, and nor do some fonts.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is possible that some paths to stylesheets and or images are still based off your previous folder structure.  Without seeing it, it is hard to say and anything is really a guess. 

Check your .htaccess as well as it may still include the subfolder path.

Are you positive you changed all references in the database?

Comment: Check if `domain.com/wpsite/` exists, note the missing `www.` it may be a cause. Check if `wp-config.php` (in the root) mentions anything regarding the default `home`. Make sure that by moving the files you didn't change file-permissions on them (folders need to be 755, files need to be 644, make sure this is recursively applied).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by checking the SQL file for all instances of www.domain.com/wpsite/ and make sure the DB is 100% correct. The easiest method for this is output the DB as SQL and open it in a text editor. Do a search and replace.

If the DB is not the issue, then some references in your CSS file might be off etc. Post an example if you can.

Comment: I think it might just be the css

Answer (score 0):

It may be that when you move the files over to the root directory the structure differs, just make sure all your links to css and other features are all correct 
if you have placed it deeper in the file structure you may need to come up a level `../filename//file.css` etc.